# How to retrieve entities by conditioning all their ManyToMany relations?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

### The context

I'm working on an online shop. Every `Product` on the website can have several `ProductVariation`s (e. g. *size*, *color*, ...) which values are a list of `ProductVariationValue` (e. g. *XL*, *L*, *Blue*, *Red*, ...).

Each `ProductVariationValue` is bound to a `ProductVariation` (e. g. you can't choose *Red* for *Size*).

I'm trying to create a stock management system which tracks the amount of in-stock `(Product, ProductVariations, ProductVariationValues)` combination.

```php
Product <--> ProductVariation <--> ProductVariationValue
```

I've managed to do it by creating a `Stock` entity holding a `Product` and a collection of `ProductVariationValues`:

```php
/** @ORM\Entity */
public class Stock
{
  // ...

  /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AcmeDemoBundle:Product") */
  protected $product;

  /** @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AcmeDemoBundle:ProductVariationValues") */
  protected $productVariationValues;

  /** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
  protected $number = 0;

  // ...
}
```

When the user adds a `Product` to his cart, I create an instance of `OrderItem` which holds the `ProductVariationValues` they selected:

```php
/** @ORM\Entity */
public class OrderItem
{
  // ...

  /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AcmeDemoBundle:Product") */
  protected $product;

  /** @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AcmeDemoBundle:ProductVariationValues") */
  protected $productVariationValues;

  // ...
}
```

### The problem

I understand the `Stock` entity is similar to the `OrderItem` entity. However, when the user adds a `Product` to his cart, and I'm building the `OrderItem` entity, I cannot find how to retrieve the `Stock` instance to check whether the `Product` with its `ProductVariationValues` are in stock, because I can't find which relation to add in the `Stock` entity.

Indeed, the `Stock` entity cannot be identified by the `$product` or `$productVariationValues` relations by themselves: they need to be put together.

### What I've tried to do

In the controller, given the `$product` and an array of `$productVariationValues`, the user selected, I've tried to set up a query to retrieve the `Stock` instance.

```php
class StockRepository
{
  public function retrieveStock($product, $productVariationValues)
  {
    $this->getQueryBuilder('s')
      ->leftJoin('s.product', 'p')
      ->leftJoin('s.productVariationValues', 'pvv')
      ->where('s.product = ?')
      ->andWhere('s.productVariationValues = ?')
      ->setParameter(1, $product)
      ->setParameter(2, $productVariationValues);

    // ...
  }
}
```

This code does not work as the `setParameter()` method can not accept `array` or `ArrayCollection` parameters.

Either way, this solution would not be optimal as this code must be run from the controller and I wouldn't be able to run it from the `OrderItem` entity.

Is my entity model wrong? Is there a simple way to add a `Stock` relation in my `OrderItem` class? Or at least to retrieve a `Stock` item, given its `Product` and `ProductVariationValues`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an IN clause, and iterate over all the values; something like:

```
class StockRepository
{
  public function retrieveStock($product, $productVariationValues)
  {
    $qb=$this->getQueryBuilder('s');
    $qb->leftJoin('s.product', 'p')
        ->leftJoin('s.productVariationValues', 'pvv')
        ->where('s.product = ?')
        ->setParameter(1, $product)
        ;
    $stockVariationValues=$qb->getQuery()-
    >getSingleResult()->getProductVariationValues();

    $qb=$this->getQueryBuilder('s');
    $qb->leftJoin('s.product', 'p')
        ->leftJoin('s.productVariationValues', 'pvv')
        ->where('s.product = ?')
        ->setParameter(1, $product)
    ;

    $stockVariationValues->map(function ($element) use ($qb){
      $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()
        ->in('s.productVariationValues'
            ,  "'".implode(","
                ,$productVariationValues->toArray())
            ."'")
        );
    });

    // ...
  }
}
```